# Link from Azure Blob downloads image, but I need to just watch (Asp.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have code to upload the image to azure blob storage

Here is code to upload image

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration.GetConnectionString("AccessKey"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("toosee");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

In result I get url

When I open it, image downloading. I need just watch it, where is my problem?

Comment: How do you open it?

Comment: @CSharpRocks I copy -paste the link. And It start to download immediately

Comment: What do you mean “I need to watch it”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please disregard this answer if it does not reflect the desired/expected behavior.*

**--- Observed ---**

**If** the web browser is downloading the image blob as follows:

[image]

**--- Expected---**

And, the desired behavior is the web browser **to render** it as follows:

[image]

**--- Fix ---**

Then, add the following line to your code:

> blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

Find below an example code:

```
    public static string UploadFile()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{Connection String}");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("toosee");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("customer_address.png");
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
        blockBlob.UploadFromFile(@"C:\\Temp\\customer_address.PNG");
        return blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

**--- References ---**

Find a list of MIME types for images at https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image.

Comment: and if I want `png`, `jpg`, `jpeg` files?
How I need to define `ContentType`

Comment: You will need to check the file extension and map content type property accordingly. Here is a list of MIME types for image https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image.